# Want to append colored images to a list and convert that list to grayscale using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So basically I'm trying to convert a set of RGB images to grayscale using cv2.cvtColor and python is throwing the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MCG.py", line 53, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar.

This here is the code:

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  
import dlib
import sys
import skimage 
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob


folderpath = sys.argv[1]
cascPath = sys.argv[2]

imageformat = ".tif"
path = folderpath
imfilelist = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(imageformat)]
data = []
for IMG in imfilelist:
   print IMG
   image = cv2.imread(IMG)
   data.append(image)
   cv2.imshow('Image', image)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)  

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)  

gray = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(  
    gray,  
    scaleFactor=1.05,  
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(100,100)
)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to append all these images to a list, which will then be converted using the cv2.cvtColor function. However, that error is thrown. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

P.S if anyone is wondering why I imported modules that don't seem to be used in this code, this code is just a segment of the whole thing and all of those modules have are being utilized in one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [cv2.cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?) documentation, you can see that the first parameter is the Src 8-bit single channel image. However, in your case you are giving an entire list of images.
So change the code as

```
gray = []
for j in range(0,len(data)):
    gray.append(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(data[j]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
```

I guess this should work.

Comment: I've tried your method and it didn't work I'm afraid. Thank you though. It still throws the same error. I decided to display the gray images by using cv2.imshow('Grayed Image', data[j]),  but they remained colored. And as I said, the exact same error persists.

Comment: Another thing you can try is cast it to a numpy array. So change the code line I have posted above to `gray.append(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(data[j]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))` . Mayb its not in the array format

Comment: It worked. Appreciate the help. casting all the arrays to numpy arrays in the above code (meaning mine) worked.

Comment: Great to hear. Since I am still new to answering questions.. sorry If my suggestion was wrong. Please do vote if you feel my answer is correct now. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You are collecting the images into a list with

```
data = []
for IMG in imfilelist:
    ...
    data.append(image)
    ....
```

and then trying to convert the list with

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This is why you are getting the error - the error is telling you that `data` is not an image (numpy array) but is a list. You need to convert one image at a time with `cv2.cvtColor()`.

You could try

```
gray = []
for img in data:
    gray.append(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
```

This would give you a list of greyscaled images, which is what I think you want to do.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! It didn't work I'm afraid. The outcome is the same. The images that have been "converted" are still colored. I used cv2.imshow('Grayed Image', img to check.. Oh and the exact same error persists.

Comment: If you have used `cv2.imshow('..', img)` following the `gray.append...` line, then yes the image will be coloured because you are displaying the colour image.

Comment: By "the exact same error", do you mean the error referenced to the line `gray = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Comment: The code segment `gray = [], for img in data: ...` should replace the `gray = cv2.cvtColor(...)` line

Comment: It worked, but only partially. It now throws the same error (src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar), but for the detectMultiScale function for the line that says minSize = (100,100). So it advanced further down the code, but threw the same error for a different line of code (mentioned above in this comment).

Comment: Same as earlier, the error is telling you that `gray` is not an image. This is because it is a __list__. _You still need to process one image at a time, you __cannot__ throw a list at it and hope for it to work._ You still need to iterate over the list.

Comment: Yeah, did that alongside the thing that the guy below recommended. It no longer throws that error and everything moved ahead. Appreciate the help